# Why radius, diameter... matter for a graph to be connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Why definitions such diameter, radius, peripheral vertex or central vertex matter that a graph to be connected?

I am not asking what the definitions mean but trying to create a relation in my head.

Comment: Technically, they have nothing to do with a true-false answer to “Is this graph connected?” “Connectivity” is, however, more complicated than that one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not grammatically correct. Other people seem to be taking it to mean "Why do diameter et al matter for whether a graph is connected?" However, I think the most logical interpretation is that you are asking "Why [is it that for] definitions such diameter, radius, peripheral vertex or central vertex[, it] matter[s] that a graph be connected?"

The diameter and radius are defined in terms of path lengths. If there is no path, then they aren't well defined. For instance, the diameter is the maximum over all $a,b$ of the minimum over all paths between $a$ and $b$ of the path length (that is, for each pair of vertices, find the minimum path length, then find the maximum value of this over all pairs of vertices). If the graph is not connected, then there is at least one pair of vertices that doesn't have any path between those vertices, so when we take the minimum path length over all paths between them, we're taking the minimum over an empty set, which doesn't work. By convention, it's often taken to be infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain this a bit. If we are simply talking about connectivity, then you are right, those definitions matter very little. What those definitions are for is something called [algebraic connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_connectivity). In this case, we want to separate a graph into components such that the connection between components are weak. We care not only about if the graph is connected, but how connected are they. Clearly, a clique is more connected than a tree. This is where those definitions come in useful.